# Windows 10 laptop does not wake with external keyboard and mouse when lid closed

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, sleep, lid

I use a Windows 10 laptop connected to an external monitor, as well as a wireless USB keyboard and mouse. I have configured the laptops's lid so that is does nothing when opened or closed. However, I am unable to wake the computer from sleep using the external keyboard and mouse when the lid was already closed when going to sleep. That is,

- if I go to sleep with the lid open, then close the lid, then touch keyboard/mouse, it works just fine
- if I enter sleep mode with the lid closed, the external keyboard and mouse will not work

Any idea? I have tried everything I have found on forums, but nothing works for me. I am using a Xiaomi Mi Notebook Air 13, which has a rather limited BIOS (hence changing BIOS settings does not seem an option for me).