# Only wake pc if lid is open

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse, wake-up, lid

Can I make my mouse only wake my laptop if the lid is open? If I forget to turn my mouse off, it wakes my laptop when moved, even when the lid is closed. This heats up the laptop, which I keep in a sleeve, and wastes battery. At the moment I have disabled "Allow this device to wake the computer" for my mouse but I want it to be able to wake the PC if the lid is open.
Specs:
HP Notebook 15-dy1751ms
Windows 10 Home 21H2 19044.1466
Logitech M510

NOTE: [Another question](https://superuser.com/q/1389616/1158529) offers the inverse of this problem, but it is unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make my mouse only wake my laptop if the lid is open? If I
> forget to turn my mouse off, it wakes my laptop when moved, even when
> the lid is closed.

I have seen this issue myself with both USB and Bluetooth mice. Depending on the mouse, it may not be possible to prevent the mouse from waking the laptop.

I do not disable the feature "Allow this device to wake the computer"

Rather, I have found the best way to deal with this issue is to either (a) remove the USB device from the computer or (b) turn the mouse off before closing the lid for moving the laptop.

(b) works for USB and Bluetooth mice and prevents problems (battery drain and even overheating).

Comment: I usually just turn off my mouse but I'm trying to solve what happens if I don't remember to. And if I forget to turn off my mouse you can be sure I'll forget to remove the USB receiver as well.

Comment: I understand your point but what I suggest is all you can do as I don’t know any mouse / connection method that can prevent this. I have travelled with my laptop daily for many years and simply had to develop the habit to turn off or face the consequences of drained battery or overheated computer

Comment: ok, thanks for your expertise